# Jquery get the href value of a div that has div sibling with particular class attributes

Tags: jquery, class, attributes

I have an html that has a div with particular class and text (in the case of the html file I am trying to work on: "All Information (Senate Website)" and the class is field__label. This particular div has a sibling or next element class "field__item" and this class field__item has a child a href. I am interested in getting the value of href attribute. How do I that with html below.

```
 <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/80559/field_a/en/full" class="field field--name-field-a field--type-link field--label-inline">
    <div class="field__label">All Information (Senate Website)</div>
              <div class="field__item"><a href="http://legacy.senate.gov.ph/lis/bill_res.aspx?congress=14&amp;q=SBN-97">View</a></div>
          </div>
```

What works for me is using the .html function (see code below) but with this code, it is giving me: `<a href="http://legacy.senate.gov.ph/lis/bill_res.aspx?congress=14&amp;q=SBN-97">View</a>`. I am only interested with `http://legacy.senate.gov.ph/lis/bill_res.aspx?congress=14&amp;q=SBN-97`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  url_sb_all = $( "div.field__label:contains('All Information ')").nextAll().html();
alert (url_sb_all);
});
```

Using innerHTML, it is giving me undefined. And using like the one below, it is also giving me undefined.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){      
var url_sb_all = $("div.field__label:contains('All Information ')" > "div.field__item a:contains('View')").prop('href');    
alert (url_sb_all);    
});
```

Comment: Try with `$( "div.field__label:contains('All Information ')").next('.field__item').find('a').attr("href")`

Comment: If the label is *always* the next element then use `.next()` (in the above comment / below answer) - if it *might* be a sibling the use `.closest(".field").find(".field__item").` assuming each `.field` has only one label+item.

Comment: Thank you very much! Carsten's answer solved what I wanted to get.

Comment: freedomn-m, I tried yours: var url_sb_all = $( "div.field__label:contains('All Information ')").closest(".field").find(".field__item"). It is giving me object object though. :(

Comment: You'll see I put `.find(..).` - ie it's just *part* - don't end with `.find()` that gives you the element (jquery), you still need `.attr("href")`.  Also, stop using `alert` for debugging as it just gives you [Object object].

Comment: Thanks freedomn-m. Yeah, console.log is that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as simple as I can get it

```js
const url = $(".field__label:contains('All Information (Senate Website)')")         // the div containing your text
  .next()        // the next sibling
  .find("a")     // the link in that sibling
  .prop("href"); // prop() or attr()
console.log(url)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-quickedit-field-id="node/80559/field_a/en/full" class="field field--name-field-a field--type-link field--label-inline">
  <div class="field__label">All Information (Senate Website)</div>
  <div class="field__item"><a href="http://legacy.senate.gov.ph/lis/bill_res.aspx?congress=14&amp;q=SBN-97">View</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This also solves the problem. Almost similar with Carsten's answer. Maybe, my mistake was not iterating over "a", used next method haphazardly. Thanks again!